# How can I create a new layout and have it show up only in certain situations using ruby padrino?

Tags: ruby, layout, default, padrino

I'm using padrino with my website, and need to override the default layout to use a different layout in certain situations i.e. when a user clicks on a certain thing.

Answer (score 0):

Padrino documentation gives these examples:

```
SimpleApp.controllers :posts do
  # Apply a layout for routes in this controller
  # Layout file would be in 'app/views/layouts/posts.haml'
  layout :posts 
  get("/posts") { render :haml, "Uses posts layout" }
end

SimpleApp.controllers :admin do
  get :index do
    render "admin/index", :layout => :admin
  end

  get :show, :with => :id do
    render "admin/show", :layout => false
  end
end
```